# Ready to use admin views for ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, admin, membership-provider, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a an `ASP.NET` `MVC5` project using Entity Framework. I have all the regular membership entities (`AspNetUser`, `AspNetRole`, ...). In the RoR or `Django` world we can add admin views extremely easily and I wonder if the ASP.NET MVC eco-system has anything similar to offer.

[image]

I'm thinking about admin views for tasks as listing users, editing user's roles, changing user fields, etc. within the standard membership realm.

I know I could scaffold views (with more plumbing code than what I'd use with Django), but I'm pretty sure I wouldn't be the first one who'd create views for managing users for standard ASP.NET MVC membership setup. I made more than enough Google searches, but I only find articles about the membership provider system.

Ideally I'm looking for a NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid currently we don't have one but you can use https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97 project to work as your administration.

Comment: I'll take a look. For the menu, sitemap, breadcrumbs, etc I use MvcSiteMapProvider which I can advise to anyone. Pretty neat.